# iPad orientation is not only four in iOS

Tags: ipad, cocoa-touch, ios5, orientation, uitextview

Now i realized when i writing my app for only iPad version.

My iPad iOS Version is iOS `5.1`.

Yes, i need to check the iPad Orientation before load my Data.

So i check with following codes.

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    {
        self.originalLandScape = CGRectMake(0, 48, 1024, 704);
        self.originalPortrait = CGRectMake(0, 48, 768, 960);

        self.txtView.frame = self.originalLandScape;
    }

    else
    {
        self.originalPortrait = CGRectMake(0, 48, 768, 960);
        self.originalLandScape = CGRectMake(0, 48, 1024, 704);

        self.txtView.frame = self.originalPortrait;
    }
```

Because i need to set the fix size to my `UITextView`.

However i realized that when my iPad is with Landscape and put down to floor horizontally , It's not correct to set `UITextView` size.

But when i get my iPad from floor and holding in my hand with `Landscape` like reading book , my above codes is work.

Is there any different between those two?

I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks you for any suggestions and helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - iPad orientation is not only four, it is six:

```
 UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
 UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight
 UIDeviceOrientationPortrait
 UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown
 UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp
 UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown
```

Your `else` clause therefore applies not just to the Portrait orientations, but to FaceUp and FaceDown as well.

I suspect that what you actually want to use is the *Interface* orientation. This may or may not be the same orientation as the *Device* orientation (depending on your app's supported orientations) - but if you want to draw a UI element correctly for a particular orientation, it will be the orientation of the rest of the interface that matters, not the device orientation.

There are only four interface orientations:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight
UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait
UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown
```

You can get these with the UIViewController property `interfaceOrientation` and check them with the UIKit functions `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape()` and `UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait()`

Try this in your code

```
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(self.interfaceOrientation))) {
   ...
} else {
   ... 
}
```